# If enough sub-addresses under a single seed are known, can that seed be reverse-engineered?

Tags: security, mnemonic-seed, address, wallet-recovery, attack

I'm gonna be accepting XMR as payment for my business. Customers purchase a single item for each transaction, so for convenience on my end I'm planning to have each product paid for through one unique sub-address per product with all sub-addresses contained within the same Account of my Wallet. So all sub-addresses are derived from the same seed.

My question is: given access to my storefront and knowing 10's to 100's of my XMR sub-addresses, could somebody interested in accessing my account reverse-engineer my wallet seed, or any other potentially damaging information?

Answer (score 2):

> If enough sub-addresses under a single seed are known, can that seed be reverse-engineered?

No.